# yeoman-App --> grunt serve --> Warning: not found: compass

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman

This is my problem:

[image: Problem]

I've installed a yeoman angular app and now i run "grunt serve".
I've installed [this](http://compass-style.org/install/). Maybe i did something wrong while installing compass. Could it be a gruntfile.js problem?

**Edit (For User555's Comment):** 
After trying to install grunt-contrib-compass i get this:

[image]

Information:
I see that this is already in the package.json and it is installed already through npm:
[image]

Comment: The warning Task "compass" not found. comes from the task not being installed and loaded. Install with npm i grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev and grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');.

Comment: I edited my post. ( see that this is already in the package.json and it is installed already through npm.. Yeoman did this already for me ) And i've edited the Gruntfile and added the 'grunt.loadNpmTask("grunt-contrib-compass")'

Comment: This is warning not error fsevents is optional dependency

Comment: ok but it didnt solve my problem: i cant "grunt serve", because the warning still shows up :/

Answer (score 0):

For those who experience the same problem: I dont know what i did wrong with the `gem install sass` stuff (it shouldnt be that hard to type this in the cli you might think).

No it isn't that hard and it is installed so all dependencies should be installed and ready for  grunt-contrib-compass / grunt-contrib-sass (I tried with both)

[Now i solved it with this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) it is a compiler in c++ so i dont need that stuff mentioned above... So actually I dont really know what was my mistake.. well now i can compile my scss files properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is compass specific version error. Follow the discussion here: https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1618. You will need to updatecompass version or rollback to 0.12.3.

Comment: this is not the problem that i have. Anyways i tried to install an older version but it didnt help